# How to optimize the launch time in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dylib

My application takes very long time to launch. I captured the launch time using the DYLD_STATISTICS. Dylib loading accounts for more than 15 seconds.
I use more than 15 third party frameworks using cocoa pods. From the WWDC, I came to know there is no option to merge the libraries.

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/406/

Could someone point me the pointers to merge the libraries or any other alternatives to reduce the dylib loading time?

Dev Environment :

- iOS version: 9.0 to 10
- Xcode 8.3
- Objective C and Swift3
- Sierra